# Why is my program not printing the right answer for Project Euler 17?

Tags: python, dictionary

Project Euler [Problem 17](https://projecteuler.net/problem=17):

> If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four,
> five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.
>
> If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were
> written out in words, how many letters would be used?
>
> NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred
> and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen)
> contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in
> compliance with British usage.

Whenever I test my code with a randomly generated number, it outputs the correct number of characters if that number were to be written in words. However, when trying to run with the provided testcase my answer is wrong. Answer: 18451

```
Words = {0: "", 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four", 5:"five", 6:"six", 7:"seven", 8:"eight", 9:"nine", 10:"ten", 11:"eleven", 12:"twelve", 13:"thirteen", 14:"fourteen", 15:"fifteen", 16:"sixteen",17:"seventeen", 18:"eighteen", 19:"nineteen", 20:"twenty", 30:"thirty", 40:"forty", 50:"fifty", 60:"sixty", 70:"seventy", 80:"eighty", 90:"ninety", 100:"onehundred", 200:"twohundred", 300:"threehundred", 400:"fourhundred", 500:"fivehundred", 600:"sixhundred", 700:"sevenhundred", 800:"eighthundred", 900:"ninehundred", 1000:"onethousand"}

count = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    c = 1
    arr = []
    if(i<=20 or (len(str(i))==2 and i%10==0)):
        count += len(Words.get(i))

    elif(i%100==0):
        count += len(Words.get(i))

    else:
        while(i!=0):
            z = i%10
            arr.append(z*c)
            i = i//10
            c*=10

        if(len(arr)==3 and arr[1]==10):
            arr[1]=arr[1]+arr[0]
            arr[0]=0
        for f in arr:
            count+=len(Words.get(f))
    
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debugged your code. You mentioned in your question that 115 (one hundred and fifteen) has 20 letters, but your program counts 17, because you did not consider "and" in your code. If you include every "and", you will get 891 * 3 + 18451 = 21124 which is i believe correct answer. Hope i am not mistaken with math.